# How to configure android emulator to auto change orientation upon rotating

Tags: android, android-emulator

Currently, when I rotate the emulator, it doesn't auto change orientation, I have to press a little icon to change its orientation. Is there a way to configure it?

I am using Android API 28.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The little icon seems only shown when auto-rotate is turned off. After I turn on auto-rotate, the emulator changes orientation automatically.

[image: Enable It]

Comment: Thanks. Guess it's because I never own an android physical device otherwise I would know.